# Unwanted CSV Output scraped from a website|Using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I'm having trouble with the CSV export result on a website I am trying to scrape data from.

Output Problems:
Output in column but just the first column and it only output's the first column of data
[image: text]

Output in rows but just one row
[image: text]

I just want it to output the typical way
[image: text]

Here's a segment of the whole site's html where my particular target is:

```
<tbody id="sitesList">
    <tr data-value="11230" class="item-row">
        <td class="text-left"><a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a> <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
            <br><span>» <a href="www.domain.com/site/11230.html" target="_blank" class="text-danger">view site details</a></span></td>
        <td>92</td>
        <td>71</td>
        <td>Do Follow</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif !important;">Education
            <br>Family &amp; Parenting
            <br>Food &amp; Drink
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>Included</td>
        <td><strong>$1</strong></td>
        <td><span data-id="11230" class="btn btn-success btn-sm addtocart">Buy Website $1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-value="11229" class="item-row">
        <td class="text-left"><a href="example1.com/" target="_blank">example1.com</a> <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
            <br><span>» <a href="www.domain.com/site/11229.html" target="_blank" class="text-danger">view site details</a></span></td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Do Follow</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif !important;">Business &amp; Finance
            <br>General: Multi-Niche
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>Included</td>
        <td><strong>$2</strong></td>
        <td><span data-id="11229" class="btn btn-success btn-sm addtocart">Buy Website $2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-value="11228" class="item-row">
        <td class="text-left"><a href="example2.com" target="_blank">example2.com</a> <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
            <div class="tooltip owner_tooltip" style="float: right;opacity: 1;width: 20px;height: 20px;background-size: 100%;"><span class="tooltiptext">Owner Verified</span></div>
            <br><span>» <a href="www.domain.com/site/11228.html" target="_blank" class="text-danger">view site details</a></span></td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>Do Follow</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif !important;">Cryptocurrency
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>Not Included</td>
        <td><strong>$3</strong></td>
        <td><span data-id="11228" class="btn btn-success btn-sm addtocart">Buy Website $3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-value="11227" class="item-row">
        <td class="text-left"><a href="example3.com" target="_blank">example3.com</a> <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
            <br><span>» <a href="www.domain.com/site/11227.html" target="_blank" class="text-danger">view site details</a></span></td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>Do Follow</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif !important;">Business &amp; Finance
            <br>Health
            <br>SEO &amp; Digital Marketing
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>Included</td>
        <td><strong>$4</strong></td>
        <td><span data-id="11227" class="btn btn-success btn-sm addtocart">Buy Website $4</span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm using selenium and here's my code:

```
siteList_tds = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody[@id='sitesList']//tr//td")
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for s in siteList_tds:
        write.writerow(s.text) ## or write.writerow([s.text])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
siteList_trs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody[@id='sitesList']//tr")
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for r in siteList_trs:
        href = r.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
        tds = r.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')
        data = []
        for td in tds:
            data.append(td.text)
        write.writerow(data.insert(0, href))
```

What this code is doing differently:

1. find the `tr` tags instead of `td` to iterate through
2. Grab `href` attribute from the `a` tag which descends from `tr`
3. Grab the rest of that row's `td` elements
4. Iterate through the `td`'s to create a list that consists of each `td.text`
5. Finally, write the `data` list to a row, but insert the `href` string at the beginning in the same line.

Comment: Tried it. Got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 10, in <module>
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

Comment: So, the xpath `"//tbody[@id='sitesList']//tr"` is not returning anything. This is impossible based on the HTML you shared. There must be something else going on. Maybe you need to wait for the page to load?

It is simply impossible that your xpath `"//tbody[@id='sitesList']//tr//td"` returns any elements but `"//tbody[@id='sitesList']//tr"` does not when used in the same spot in the code.

Comment: Tried just looping the result without saving to csv, I did get a list but all data loop results are: None.
Tried this, got the data expected but there are still repeats on the output. Here's the output:
![text](https://i.imgur.com/eSWftFT.png)

Here's the edit I made:
`with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for r in siteList_trs:
        href = r.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
        tds = r.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')
        data = []
        for td in tds:
            data.append(td.text)
            write.writerow(data)`

Comment: Are `href` and `tds` having `None`?